# How to upload images to cloudinary and receive a remote url with .png or .jpeg at the end of the url expo react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, cloudinary

I am using expo-cli for my react native project and need to store the images inputed through expo image picker into a fileserver. This is when I came across cloudinary and it seems like a good solution to my problem as react native accepts only links with .png, .jpg or .jpeg at the end of them and cloudinary stores the images this way!

I want to know how I can use expo image picker to pick an image and store it in cloudinary and get the images url for storing it in my database.

Any help will be appreciated!
Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: I already have done a lot of research the do some research link that you have sent contains only purple links. Please I beg you to tell me how to do it

Comment: This is a common case I think. Maybe really very easy. You should do more research. After picking an image, you can get the file content, call an API to save it, and get the URL back.

Comment: Alright I have learnt the uploading of the image but now I want to get the url of that image and save it how do I do that? In the data i do get the url and I have tried saving the state but it doesnt go into my db! @gwl002

Comment: I don't use expo. But I think is similar! I will find some old code and paste it. Hope that will helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do with cloudinary as I have never used it.But I think is similar.Call a ajax to upload the file,and it will return you the url. Below is some old code.

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        console.log('Response = ', response);
        if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
        }
        else if (response.error) {
            console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        }
        else if (response.customButton) {
            console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        }
        else {
            let fileSize = response.fileSize / 1024 / 1024;
            if (fileSize > 5) {
                Alert.alert(null, I18n.t("myHealth.PhotoLarger"), [{ text: I18n.t("common.OK") }]);
                return;
            }
            // You can also display the image using data:
            // let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
            let ext = ".jpg";
            let matched = response.uri.match(/\.\w+$/);
            if (matched) {
                ext = matched[0];
            }
            let fileUri = Platform.OS === "android" ? ('file://' + response.path) : response.uri;
            let file = {
                name: `image${ext}`,
                type: response.type,
                uri: fileUri
            }
            // console.warn(fileUri, "=======")
            saveUserIcon(file)
        }
});
```

upload ajax

```
function saveUserIcon(file){
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append("file", file);
    http.post("/saveUserIcon", form, {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    })
}
```